# My Task processes seem to be stalling indefinitely

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I'm building an application with Elixir, which has a bunch of workers (perhaps 100-200 at any given time). These workers operate independently to eachother, they are not "pooled", all they do is pop jobs off a Redis queue, do some work and maybe pop some more jobs back onto the queue (see code below).

These workers are simply supervised Tasks which within themselves call a tail recursive function that asks for a job to do, if there is one, all is well, if there isn't one, it will `:timer.sleep` for one second and then run again.

The problem is that after some time of these workers doing there thing (exactly as expected), they will progressively stop doing that.

I have had a look at them in Observer and I can see some interesting things:

- When an error occurs, the workers restart, as defined in their `:one_for_one` supervision policy.
- The workers who have been restarted can be identified by their significantly higher PIDs.
- Workers who have become unresponsive / stalled have the same PIDs originally assigned.
- If I manually kill one of these workers within Observer, it restarts fine and gets on with it's job.

I'm kind of stumped as to what's going on here and how to remedy it. I am also interested to know if this is a "bad" way to manage larger amounts of workers like this, and if so, is there a better way?

#### Supervisor

```
defmodule Workers.DomainSupervisor do
  def start_link do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = 1..50 |> Enum.map(fn (i) -> worker(Task, [&Workers.Domain.worker/0], [id: {Workers.Domain, i}]) end)

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Workers.DomainSupervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

#### Worker

```
defmodule Workers.Domain do
  def worker do
    case Store.Domains.pop do
      :empty ->
        IO.puts "[Domain] none found, waiting..."
        :timer.sleep(1000)
      {crawl_id, domain} ->
        IO.puts "[Domains] found a domain to check: #{domain}"
        case Core.check_domain(domain) do
          :error ->
            Utils.insert(crawl_id, domain, false)
          :registered ->
            Utils.insert(crawl_id, domain, false)
          :available ->
            Utils.insert(crawl_id, domain, true)
        end
    end
    worker()
  end
end
```

#### Stack trace for a "stalled" worker (they all look the same)

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: What does Observer say these processes that have stalled are doing (the "Current Function" column)? Is there MsgQ/Reds/Memory value increasing in Observer when they're stalled?

Comment: @Dogbert Current Function is `gen:do_call/4` (right now I have a running state where all of the workers are "stalled"), same function for all of them. They all also have 0 reds and seem to keep the same value for memory over time (to be clear, all of the workers do not have the same memory value).

Comment: What do `Core.check_domain/1`, `Utils.insert/3`, and `Store.Domains.pop/0` do? Do they make a GenServer call? Do you have a timeout value for all those calls?

Comment: `Core.check_domain/1` makes a HTTP request with the HTTPoison library (hackney) and conditionally another with the Whois library (no GenServers I am aware of). `Utils.insert/1` inserts a row into postgres with Ecto, and `Store.Domains.pop/0` makes a call to Redis using Redix from a home-rolled pooling mechanism (similar to the way my workers work, except randomly passing a call to one of 10 Redix connections).

Comment: I have pretty much ruled out `Store.Domains.pop/0` as I have another type of worker which never stalls as it also calls a function which uses this Redix worker pool, and works in exactly the same manner, casing on the returned (or not returned) item, just a different Redis Set.

Comment: The amount of workers I have running at any given time seems to affect how fast they go into this odd state, or if ever (to some degree). More workers seems to equal more stalls. To be clear this is something that seems largely random, sometimes i'll start the application up and it will run great for an hour, with only a couple stalling. Sometimes they will all stall in 2 minutes.

Comment: What's the Stacktrace of the stalled process? (Double click the process in Observer and click on the Stack Trace tab.)

Comment: @Dogbert Added a screenshot to original post, seems to be related to hackney's pooling (?)

Comment: Yep, hackney_pool makes a gen_server call with infinite timeout when it needs to fetch a socket from the pool: https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/ea2012f0d4d97c1ec1a50e840168dff5b48ab97d/src/hackney_pool.erl#L66-L67. If you're making a lot of requests you probably want to increase the pool size.

Comment: Still testing but that ~seems~ to have fixed it, thanks so much! Write this into an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Could you check where exactly `hackney_pool` process is stuck (stack trace) in Observer? I don't think the pool is supposed to hang even if it's full. This _might_
 be a bug.

Comment: I suggest trying to disable the hackney pools at all and see what happens. See here: https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#use-the-default-pool